# Limiting number of lines and letters in single line in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

**Problem:**
I am trying to limit number of lines AND letters in each line in a textbox.

**What i got so far:**
So far i managed to limit lines count using this:

```
var text = $(this).val();
var lines = text.split("\n");

if(e.keyCode == 13 && lines.length >= $(this).attr('rows')) { 
        return false;
    }
```

This won't allow user to push return key (keyCode 13) if the limit of lines is reached.

**The problem:**
Now i am trying to limit number of letters in a single line too, because if i reach end of my textarea (with return key) i still can hold a letter/write tons of text, and it will jump to another line when it reaches end of line. That way this limitation can be "cheated" and i am looking for a solution for that.

**My ideas, not solving the problem:**

```
else{
    for(var i = 0; i < lines.length && e.keyCode != 13; i++) {
         if(lines[i].length >= $(this).attr('cols')) {
             return false; // prevent characters from appearing
         }
     }
}
```

I tried this to limit number of letters. That works, but it got flaws. If i reach max letters in one line (***ANY***), i ***CANT TYPE IN ANY LINE*** anymore.

**I have no idea how to check only line i am typing in RIGHT NOW.**

Comment: dont forget about right click cut/copy/paste and CTRL-X/C/V/Y. (have fun!)

Comment: oh god, right, i see thats gonna be impossible for me, or just not worth it. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tested in chrome :
http://jsfiddle.net/3e3EH/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var textArea = $('#foo');
    var maxRows = textArea.attr('rows');
    var maxChars = textArea.attr('cols');
    textArea.keypress(function(e){
        var text = textArea.val();
        var lines = text.split('\n');
        if (e.keyCode == 13){
            return lines.length < maxRows;
        }
        else{
            var caret = textArea.get(0).selectionStart;
            console.log(caret);

            var line = 0;
            var charCount = 0;
            $.each(lines, function(i,e){
                charCount += e.length;
                if (caret <= charCount){
                    line = i;
                    return false;
                }
                //\n count for 1 char;
                charCount += 1;
            });

            var theLine = lines[line];
            return theLine.length < maxChars;
        }
    });

});​
```

### Edit

As jbabey pointed out, ctrl+v or right-click -> paste can be an issue. right click can easily be prevented. for ctrl+v, you probable can detect it too...
Just disabling javascript will obviously break the thing, too.
Anyways, as any client-side validation, you *have to* double check on server-side.

Comment: Looks great, will do some more testing, but its really promising!

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I came up with.  Fairly clean and seems to work for all the tests I can give it.

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    $('textarea').on('keypress', function (event) {
        var text = $('textarea').val();
        var lines = text.split("\n");
        var currentLine = this.value.substr(0, this.selectionStart).split("\n").length;
        console.log(lines);
        console.log(currentLine);
        console.log(lines[currentLine - 1]);
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            if (lines.length >= $(this).attr('rows')) return false;
        } else {
            if (lines[currentLine - 1].length >= $(this).attr('cols')) {
                return false; // prevent characters from appearing
            }
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="15"></textarea>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GXZZg/2/)

Comment: i meant post the code as text in the answer, not post the link again.

Comment: +1, link didn't die, but I have edited your answer to include what you had in JsFiddle.

Comment: `if ( .... && event.keyCode != 8)` should stop preventing the user from using backspace after reaching the limit.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looping over each line get the current line number of your cursor and check only the character length of that line. See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9185820/5926) for implementation details.

Then change your else statement to look like this:

```
else{
    var currLine = getLineNumber();
    if (lines[currLine].length >= $(this.attr('cols')) {
        return false; // prevent characters from appearing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but i made this plugin https://github.com/luisdalmolin/jquery-limitLines.

Can be usefull sometimes.