# Getting Line Number In Text Area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find out the 'line' (row) number of the cursor in a textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185630/find-out-the-line-row-number-of-the-cursor-in-a-textarea)

I want to find out the line number that a user's cursor in on in a HTML `textarea` element.

Is this possible using javascript and jquery?

Comment: Define lines in a textarea. Does it include wrapped text or do you only want to consider newlines?

Comment: I want to set 15 character limit in one line and user should not be able to enter more than 75 chars in 5 lines

Comment: nice question realy :) Like and Bookmark ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This works with button click. Stolen from [Find out the 'line' (row) number of the cursor in a textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185630/find-out-the-line-row-number-of-the-cursor-in-a-textarea)

```
​function getline()
{
    var t = $("#t")[0];
    alert(t.value.substr(0, t.selectionStart).split("\n").length);
}​
```

HTML

```
​<textarea rows="6" id="t">
there is no
love in the ghetto
so come here
and get it
</textarea>
<input type="button" onclick="getline()" value="get line" />​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: This does not account for linebreaks caused by word wrapping.

Comment: @RobW: I don't think the OP needs that

Comment: It worked for me...Its helpfull

Comment: @codingbiz: it was so perfect...i just copy and pasted it...and it has worked...i was in this problem for past 1 week...but i have released now....thank u..

Comment: @freelance Celebrate your luck

Comment: @codingbiz: sir, will you please look at below link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600626/memory-corrupt-error

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596413/attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory. what are you doing with oledb? can you change it to an alternative. Read the link first

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following approach

1. [Find the caret positio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-caret-position-in-textarea)n (index).
2. Find the substring from position 0 to index
3. Search for number of new lines in the substring obtained in step 2.

// Test

```
$(function() {
    $('#test').keyup(function() {
        var pos = 0;
        if (this.selectionStart) {
            pos = this.selectionStart;
        } else if (document.selection) {
            this.focus();

            var r = document.selection.createRange();
            if (r == null) {
                pos = 0;
            } else {

                var re = this.createTextRange(),
                rc = re.duplicate();
                re.moveToBookmark(r.getBookmark());
                rc.setEndPoint('EndToStart', re);

                pos = rc.text.length;
            }
        }
        $('#c').html(this.value.substr(0, pos).split("\n").length);
    });
});
​
```

Here is a working example
http://jsfiddle.net/S2yn3/1/

Comment: What about lines caused by linebreaks?

Comment: Did you mean wordwrap?

Comment: Yes, linebreaks caused by wordwrapping...

Comment: It is difficult to detect linebreaks caused by wordwrapping, unless you are using a fixed width font.

Answer (score 1):

This can be split up in three steps:

- [Caret position in textarea, in characters from the start](https://stackoverflow.com/q/263743/1048572)
- [How to get the number of lines in a textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2035910/1048572) / [JavaScript: How to add line breaks to an HTML textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/863779/1048572)
- get the lines before the caret, and count them.

I guess you don't want to consider wrapped text and scrolled content. Assuming you use the function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263796/1048572), it would be like:

```
var el = document.getElementById("inputarea"); // or something

var pos = getCaret(el),
    before = el.value.substr(0, pos),
    lines = before.split(/\r?\n/);
return lines.length;
```