# Memory corrupt error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I have made one c# application For estate Agent Management.

In that application i have one mdi form which has all the menus in it.

In that menu when i selects agent master , one form comes with Add agent button.

When On Add Agent button is clicked Another Window is opened with agent details to fill.

My problem is>> when i closes this form>>

```
"Attempt to read or write protected memory.This often an indication that other memory is corrupt"
```

Error Comes.
When i clicks ok on the message box of this application whole application gets closed.

When i normally runs the application through visual studio this error doesnt comes.

But when i runs the exe of the code this error comes.

Is there any solution for this error?

Am i making mistake in releasing or debugging the project?

My stack trace:

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr wndProc, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.DefWndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Anamol Estate
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///E:/Anamol%20Estate/Anamol%20Estate/Anamol%20Estate/bin/x86/Release/Anamol%20Estate.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.EnterpriseServices
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>
```

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.

Comment: do you have any com or unmanaged interops?

Comment: What third party libraries are you using?

Comment: @Daniel A. White: no i dont have any

Comment: @ Zdeslav Vojkovic: i am including normal libraries.no third party libraries or ther installation for this. Using OLEDB connection

Comment: What are 'normal libraries'? Are there any Closing/Closed event handlers for your windows?

Comment: @ Zdeslav Vojkovic: no sir. initially i also thought on that event part. But there are no such closing events present in my code

Comment: can you show a call stack from the exception? Do you have any GUI controls built for older versions of .NET framework being used in 4.0 project?

Comment: @freelancer: look into `Application` log. Is there any errors, related to your executable?

Comment: No sir, when i runs each part of the application separatly, it does not shows me error. but when i runs exe...this error comes.

Comment: @Zdeslav Vojkovic: do you want to see screen shot of the error message?

Comment: "when i runs each part of the application separatly, it does not shows me error. but when i runs exe"??? how do you 'run separately'? for sure you also start some exe?

Comment: no, I want to see the text of the call stack contained in the exception.

Comment: I have uploaded its image sir, please have a look at it

Comment: do you know what a stack trace is? additionally, "no" meant "no, I don't want to see the screenshot". Please read my previous comment. screenshot is useless

Comment: I dont know about it. Do you want to see my code ?

Comment: I believe that you first need to learn the basic about how computer programs execute, function calls, stack etc. Sorry it this sounds rude, it is not meant to be, but you are missing some fundamental things. I have no idea how to help.

Comment: Look at your screenshoot. Do you see the button 'Details'. Click it and you will find the StackTrace there. Post that text appending to your question.

Comment: thank you steve sir...just a minute i will do that

Comment: @ Zdeslav Vojkovic: i have added stack trace.

Comment: There is something relative to a textbox or similar on your closing form. Sorry, but without specific code to look at is impossible for me to help. If you have code that executes at the form closing try to post it. Also try to set breakpoint in your events and look if something is invoked at closing time.

Comment: there is no specifc form closing event i have written and about break point...it is of no use because it runs perfectly through visual studio. But the problem is only for exe

Comment: If the error only occurs when shutting down, it would sound like something is trying to access a control/resource that has just been disposed. To try to track down why, I would suggest you disable as much functionally before you close your form. For example if you have any background threads or timers running, then stop them manually before shutting down. If you have any databinding or validation/on leave events, disable them. If all else fails, you may need to take a copy of your project and selectively strips bits out of it until either it works, or you have a trival example that goes wrong.

Comment: You can try to disable the visual studio hosting process (it's in the project properties, under "debug") to see if it's that that is masking the problem in VS. Otherwise you can start the app and attach the debugger as soon as it's started. This way you might be able to get some extra information.

Comment: Please provide us with the code around the opening form and the code inside agent master form, so that we can fix your problem

Comment: When you run your program from Visual Studio, it is likely running as a debug build, with optimizations turned off. What build type are you using when you compile your program: Debug or Release? Is `Optimize code` enabled? (You can check by looking at _Project properties_ > _Build_) What happens when you compile a Debug build with `Optimize code` unchecked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET Framework has similar problem. Try this [fix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923028).

When you run a Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 Remoting application, you may receive the following error message:
Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
Additionally, this problem may occur in .NET Framework 2.0 Remoting applications on a computer that is running certain types of driver software or antivirus programs.

Comment: should i download that hotfix and problem will get solved? or somewhere they are also telling to wait till next version comes.

Comment: This reason might be most possible. There are also other reasons but I need more information about this problem. Just try to perform this fix. You have no one risk in this case.

Comment: the link is dead

Answer (score 0):

First you can try a [memtest](http://www.memtest.org/) as there could maybe be a specific sector of your memory which when allocated to is causing this error. The latest current version is 4.2 the downloads section is a quite a scroll down.

Or

This has happened to me once before it was due to a virus changing headers in my exe files. I had formatted my pc and reinstalled everything and it worked fine in my case. I suggest you try this option.

Comment: but i have installed it on 3 different machines and all of them are giving problems

Comment: I am sorry then I don't know were the problem can be coming from.