# How to find the line number of classes and function of program in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, bash, textarea

I want to store the line number of classes and function of java program written in a textarea. I was following this link posted by me [Storing the line number of all the occurrence of particular character in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54178687/storing-the-line-number-of-all-the-occurrence-of-particular-character-in-javascr]) with the logic that the classes and the function starts with "{" but it will not work if loop or condition statement comes in a program.

Here is a textarea content:

```
public class Largest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] numArray = { 23.4, -34.5, 50.0, 33.5, 55.5, 43.7, 5.7, -66.5 };
    double largest = numArray[0];

    for (double num: numArray) {
        if(largest < num)
            largest = num;
    }

    System.out.format("Largest element = %.2f", largest);
    }
}
```

The output: `Array content is... 1 3 4 7`. I want the array output only `1,3`.

Please suggest me approach of how to identify and find the line number of classes and function.

Comment: You could work with something like a stack. Increment a counter by the occurance of `{` and decrement it by the occurance of `}`. Then you can be sure that if the counter goes from 0 to 1, you'll encounter the start and if it goes from 1 to 0, the end of a class. The same goes for methods but with the numbers 1 and 2, respectively 2 and 1